# How to get relative path of hyperlink when click it in local HTA file

Tags: javascript, hta

I need to get relative path of a hyperlink when I click by it in HTA file without following by the link.

Consider for example this simple **test.hta**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9.0" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<a href="/href1">Link1</a>
<a href="/href2">Link2</a>
<script>
var pageLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for(i = 0; i < pageLinks.length; i++) {
    var href = pageLinks[i].href;
    pageLinks[i].href = '#!'+href;
    pageLinks[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(this.href.substring(3));
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click by any hyperlink e.g. the first one, I get absolute path

> e:///D:/path/to/test.hta#!file:///D:/href1

How can I get `href1` instead?

Comment: Try to get rid of the '/' in the href=/href `<a href="href1">Link1</a>` - relative link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, the solution is so simple. It's enough to use `.getAttribute('href')` instead of `.href` in both places where I get the attribute.